# i keep having an error about a .nib file that i don't know how has been created

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I keep having this error:

> Impossible create:
>   "C:\PROGETTI\App\ios\App1\App1\obj\iPhoneSimulator\Debug\ibtool-link\Main.storyboardc\153890-view-153891.nib"Because
>   already exist a file or directory named this way.

I don't know what to do cause i can't debug.
Actually i'm using visual studio on windows 10 and a mac with mojave as server and i debug directly on the mac via xcode simulator.

Comment: Have you tried to rease simulator content and settings, and clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Yes, and now works, thx, but what can cause such error?

Comment: Sometimes it happens, with Xamarin its more common than expected. I will post this as an answer for future problems, please mark it as correct and don't forget to upvote :) . @Jacob Richardson

Comment: Thx a lot for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Erase Simulator Content and Settings
2. Clean and Rebuild your project

Usually these types of errors can be handled this way. Probably an error deleting a file.